# Jupyter Notebook kernel restarts every time I import pixiedust

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, macos-big-sur

Running one line of code "import pixiedust" makes the kernel die and automatically restart every time I try it. I'm using Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda in **MacOS BigSur 11.2.3**.

`import pixiedust`

this is my only line of code, the rest of my code works fine (the part not using pixiedust).

that's the terminal output:

```
Last login: Sat Mar 27 16:26:47 on ttys001
/Users/avic/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;                       
(base) avic@Avis-MBP ~ % /Users/avic/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
[I 16:31:00.239 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /Users/avic/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 16:31:00.239 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /Users/avic/opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 16:31:00.242 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/avic
[I 16:31:00.242 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 16:31:00.242 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=8d705f0c1f4efa59a8d4edc4643ad87ded410f4af2f62ea6
[I 16:31:00.242 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=8d705f0c1f4efa59a8d4edc4643ad87ded410f4af2f62ea6
[I 16:31:00.242 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 16:31:00.249 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///Users/avic/Library/Jupyter/runtime/nbserver-57976-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=8d705f0c1f4efa59a8d4edc4643ad87ded410f4af2f62ea6
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=8d705f0c1f4efa59a8d4edc4643ad87ded410f4af2f62ea6
[I 16:31:09.251 NotebookApp] Kernel started: b3400759-7e32-4b4d-87c8-77676fafe504
[I 16:31:15.255 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
kernel b3400759-7e32-4b4d-87c8-77676fafe504 restarted
```

I've never used this workspace before but I'm required to by my uni...

Please help :)